# problemas con ModelState.IsValid no respeta los required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

estoy haciendo validaciones a los campos de texto de un formulario a traves de un model que decoro con [Required] para requerir ciertos campos pero cn el controlador cuando hago la condicion if (ModelState.IsValid) no realiza el guardado en la BD ya que el modelo no es valido hasta ingresar todos los campos, como puedo hacer para que solo los tres campos que uso con el required en el modelo sean solo los obligatorios y no los demas

vista

```html
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Table tbody > tr').remove();
        MuestraTodasLasVariables();
        $('#btnGuarda').click(function () {
            
            var url = "http://localhost:6892/Validador/AgregarVariable";
            var data = new FormData();

            var data = {
                items: {
                    VariableNombre: $('#txtNombreVariable').val()
                    , DatoTipo: $('#DDLTipoDato').val()
                    , NumeroDecimales: $('#txtNumDecimales').val()
                    , ValorConstante: $('#txtValorFijo').val()
                    , ValorMinimo: $('#txtValMinimo').val()
                    , ValorMaximo: $('#txtValMaximo').val()
                    , ValorIncremento: $('#txtIncremento').val()
                    , IdVariableIdentificador: $('#DDLIDVariable').val()
                }
            };

            $.ajax({
                
                type: "Post",
                url: url,
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                processData: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (data) {
                    
                    if (data.Success === true) {
                        $('#Table tbody > tr').remove();
                        MuestraTodasLasVariables();
                        $('#txtNombreVariable').val('');
                        $('#DDLIDVariable').val(0);
                        $("#DDLTipoDato option[value='- Seleccione -']").prop("selected", true);
                        $('#txtNumDecimales').val('');
                        $('#txtValorFijo').val('');
                        $('#txtValMinimo').val('');
                        $('#txtValMaximo').val('');
                        $('#txtIncremento').val('');
                        $('#DDLIDVariable').val(0)

                        //alert("Se ha agregado una variable exitosamente!");
                        //$('.ModalGuardadoVariable').click();
                        messageOK('Aviso', data.Mensaje);
                    }
                    else {
                        //alert("Hubo un error. Intentelo nuevamente");
                        //$('.ModalNoGuardadoVariable').click();
                        messageOK('Aviso', data.Mensaje);
                    }
                    //    alert(data.mensaje);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorthrow) {
                    //alert(xhr.error);
                    //alert("error en proceso");
                }
            });


        });


    });
    function MuestraTodasLasVariables() {
        var url = "http://localhost:6892/Validador/TodasLasVariables";
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: url,
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success === true) {

                    $.each(data.Variables, function (i, registro) {

                        var trs = $("#Table tr").length;
                        var nuevaFila = "<tr>";

                        nuevaFila += '<td>';
                        nuevaFila += '' + registro.NombreVaribale + '';
                        nuevaFila += '</td >';
                        nuevaFila += '<td>';
                        nuevaFila += '' + registro.TipoDato + '';
                        nuevaFila += '</td >';

                        nuevaFila += "</tr>";
                        $("#Table").append(nuevaFila);

                    });
                    if ($('#Table >tbody >tr').length == 0) {
                        // alert("No hay filas en la tabla!!");
                        $('#TablaMostrarVariables').css('display', 'none');
                        //$("#msgTabla").removeAttr("style", "display:none");
                        $('#MsgTabla').css('display', 'block');
                    } 
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorthrow) {
                //alert(xhr.error);
                //alert("error en proceso");
            }

        });
    }
</script>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <h3>Agregar Variable</h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Bienvenido: @ViewBag.Usuario</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
        @Html.ActionLink("Cerrar sesión", "Index", "Home")
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-left col-md-8">
            <div class="container">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-left col-md-4" style="padding-top:10px">
            <div class="text-right">
                @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "AgregarFormula", "Validador", new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                <button id="btnGuarda" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">

            @*using (Html.BeginForm("AgregarVariable", "Validador", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formulaForm" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary()*@

            <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Nombre de la variable:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("txtNombreVariable", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Identificador de Variable:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("DDLIDVariable", ViewBag.VariablesIdentificador as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "DDLIDVariable" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Tipo de dato:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("DDLTipoDato", ViewBag.TipoDato as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "DDLTipoDato" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">No. de decimales:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("txtNumDecimales", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Valor fijo:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("txtValorFijo", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Valor minimo:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("txtValMinimo", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Valor maximo:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("txtValMaximo", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Incremento:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("txtIncremento", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

            <btn id="ModalGuarda" type="button" class="btn btn-default ModalGuardadoVariable" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalGuardadoVariable" style="display:none;">Abrir ventana de aviso de termino de captura</btn>
            <btn id="ModalAvisaNoGuardo" type="button" class="btn btn-default ModalNoGuardadoVariable" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalNoGuardadoVariable" style="display:none;">Abrir ventana de aviso de empate</btn>

        </div>
    </div>
   
    <div id="TablaMostrarVariables" style="display:block">
        <hr />
        <table id="Table" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Nombre Variable</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Tipo de Dato</th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="MsgTabla" style="display:none">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <strong>No hay variables</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult AgregarVariable(entVariables items)
    {
        /*Obtener valores de la sección Crear Variable*/
        var VariableNombre = items.VariableNombre;
        var DatoTipo = items.DatoTipo;
        Int16 valorNumeroDecimales = Convert.ToInt16(items.NumeroDecimales);
        Decimal valorFijo = Convert.ToDecimal(items.ValorConstante);
        Decimal valorMinimo = Convert.ToDecimal(items.ValorMinimo);
        Decimal valorMaximo = Convert.ToDecimal(items.ValorMaximo);
        Decimal valorIncremento = Convert.ToDecimal(items.ValorIncremento);
        Int16 valorIdentificadorVariable = Convert.ToInt16(items.IdVariableIdentificador);

        bool success = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[9];

                prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@nombreVariable", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                prms[0].Value = VariableNombre;

                prms[1] = new SqlParameter("@tipoDato", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                prms[1].Value = DatoTipo;

                prms[2] = new SqlParameter("@numeroDecimales", SqlDbType.Int);
                prms[2].Value = valorNumeroDecimales;

                prms[3] = new SqlParameter("@valorFijo", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                prms[3].Value = valorFijo;

                prms[4] = new SqlParameter("@valorMinimo", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                prms[4].Value = valorMinimo;

                prms[5] = new SqlParameter("@valorMaximo", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                prms[5].Value = valorMaximo;

                prms[6] = new SqlParameter("@valorIncremento", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                prms[6].Value = valorIncremento;

                prms[7] = new SqlParameter("@valorIdentificadorVariable", SqlDbType.Int);
                prms[7].Value = valorIdentificadorVariable;

                prms[8] = new SqlParameter("@Activo", SqlDbType.Bit);
                prms[8].Value = 1;

                object resultado = DB.EjecutarEscalar("SP_GuardarVariables", prms);

                success = true;
                //return Json(new { Success = success, Mensaje = "OK" });
                return Json(new { Success = success, Mensaje = "Se guardo la variable exitosamente." });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //return Json(new { Success = success, Mensaje = "hubo un error" });
                return Json(new { Success = success, Mensaje = "Ocurrio una excepción" });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            List<entVariables> lstErrores = new List<entVariables>();

            if (items.VariableNombre == null || items.VariableNombre == "")
            {
                entVariables error1 = new entVariables();
                error1.NombreInput = "txtNombreVariable";
                error1.MensajeError = "El campo nombre es requerido";
                error1.EstilosError = "1px solid #FF0000";

                lstErrores.Add(error1);
            }
            else
            {
                entVariables error1 = new entVariables();
                error1.NombreInput = "txtNombreVariable";
                error1.MensajeError = "";
                error1.EstilosError = "1px solid #ccc";

                lstErrores.Add(error1);
            }

            if (items.IdVariableIdentificador == 0)
            {
                entVariables error1 = new entVariables();
                error1.NombreInput = "DDLIDVariable";
                error1.MensajeError = "El campo nombre es requerido";
                error1.EstilosError = "1px solid #FF0000";

                lstErrores.Add(error1);
            }
            else
            {
                entVariables error1 = new entVariables();
                error1.NombreInput = "DDLIDVariable";
                error1.MensajeError = "";
                error1.EstilosError = "1px solid #ccc";

                lstErrores.Add(error1);
            }

            if (items.DatoTipo == "- Seleccione -")
            {
                entVariables error1 = new entVariables();
                error1.NombreInput = "DDLTipoDato";
                error1.MensajeError = "El campo nombre es requerido";
                error1.EstilosError = "1px solid #FF0000";

                lstErrores.Add(error1);
            }
            else
            {
                entVariables error1 = new entVariables();
                error1.NombreInput = "DDLTipoDato";
                error1.MensajeError = "";
                error1.EstilosError = "1px solid #ccc";

                lstErrores.Add(error1);
            }


            return Json(new { Success = success, Mensaje = "<center>Faltan campos por capturar.</center>", Error = lstErrores });
        }


    }
```

Model

```
    public class entVariables
{
    /*Propiedades Variable*/
    [Required]
    public string VariableNombre { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IdVariableIdentificador { get; set; }
    public string ValorVariableIdentificador { get; set; }
    public int IDDatoTipo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DatoTipo { get; set; }
    public int NumeroDecimales { get; set; }
    public int ValorConstante { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorMinimo { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorMaximo { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorIncremento { get; set; }
    public string NombreInput { get; set; }
    public string MensajeError { get; set; }
    public string EstilosError { get; set; }
    public int IDNuevaVariable { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando jQuery unobstrusive?

Comment: no, no uso esa libreria

Answer (score 2):

Otra vía es modificando tu modelo agregando ? al atributo que desees, para indicar que se admiten valores null. ejemplo:

```
public int? ValorConstante { get; set; }
```

de esta forma te dejará pasar. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Te va a pasar siempre con propiedades del tipo **int**. Al no pasar ningún valor (el cero sería por defecto) en el post seguramente esté asignando *null* con lo cual para una propiedad del tipo **int** hace fallar el ***"required"*** que tiene nativo.

Para esto se me ocurren dos soluciones rápidas.

1. Asignar 0 (cero) si no se indica el valor en la vista.
2. Omitir la validación, para esto último lo podes hacer utilizando **[Bind(Exclude = {nombrePropiedad})]**

Ejemplo:

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult AgregarVariable([Bind(Exclude = "NumeroDecimales", "ValorConstante")] entVariables items)
{
  //tu código...
}
```

Espero que te sirva!